# How to get google handle_geolocation_query map to display directions from users location

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
var endlocation = {
    'center': '52.5606064,2.0312582999999904',
    'zoom': 10
};
var start = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handle_geolocation_query);
var themap;
var destination = "Wednesbury, WS10 7TB";

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#map').gmap({
        'center': endlocation.center,
        'zoom': endlocation.zoom,
        'disableDefaultUI': true,
        'callback': function () {
            themap = this;

            $('#submit').click(function () {
                themap.displayDirections({
                    'origin': start,
                    'destination': destination,
                    'travelMode': google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
                    'unitSystem': google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL
                }, {
                    'panel': document.getElementById('directions')
                },

                function (response, status) {
                    (status === 'OK') ? $('#results').show() : $('#results').hide();
                });
                return false;
            });
        }
    });
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handle_geolocation_query);
});

function handle_geolocation_query(position) {
    start = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
    themap.get('map').panTo(start);
}
```

I cant seem to figure out what I should pass to the handle_geolocation_query to get the map
to give directions from the users location to a fixed point. Thanks in advance for any help and sorry I'm a noob to maps. Heres the html:

```
<div id="map" style="height:500px;"><div>
```

Comment: You need to use the [directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/)

Answer (score 0):

If the rest of your code works, this should do the same as the submit, but automatically when the handle_geolocation_query function is run.

```
function handle_geolocation_query(position) {
  start = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
  themap.displayDirections({
                'origin': start,
                'destination': destination,
                'travelMode': google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
                'unitSystem': google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL
            }, {
                'panel': document.getElementById('directions')
            },
            function (response, status) {
                (status === 'OK') ? $('#results').show() : $('#results').hide();
            });
 });
```